# XML saving doesn't work on filesystem

Tags: php, xml, save

I tried many ways to save xml file on my filesystem, but it doesn't work. I don't know what can I do...
I only want to read an xml file, then modify the value of a node, and then save this file... But nothing happened. In PHP I don't know what the problem. In Java okay... but I need to do in PHP.

XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<node>
    <pass>test</pass>
</node>


public static function saveToXML()
    {
        $xml = simplexml_load_file(dirname(__FILE__).'/../../../../sms_data.xml');
        $xml->pass = "000";

        $dom = new DOMDocument('1.0');
        $dom->preserveWhiteSpace = false;
        $dom->formatOutput = true;
        $dom->loadXML($xml->asXML());
        echo $dom->saveXML();

    }
```

The $xml is contains the modified values. It is good, but the save function doesn't wanna work!

I tried this too: `echo $dom->save('text.xml');` But nothing. It doesn't create the text.xml file... I don't know... I have been searching for the solutions on google for one day. But I don't know what the hell is going to always wrong. I didnt get nothing. The server log is empty about it...

I am so sorry to ask this. But I don't understand this code why doesn't work... why doesn't save the modification on filesystem level!

Comment: Did you try to write to a specific directory which is also writable, e.g. $dom->save('/mydir/text.xml'); ?

Answer (score 0):

Check if the directory exists and is writable.